# PageDown in Column Selection Mode in Intellij/PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

`Column Selection Mode` is a great feature of `Intellij` (/`Pycharm` etc). I just noticed that it stops working when I hit page-down with select. Is this a known issue? it is possible that it could be platform specific. I am on `mac-os` and had to customize page-down-with-select to have it usable on my macbook pro that has limited keys available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered I had been using  `Move Caret Down with Selection` and not `Page down with Selection`.  I made a custom shortcut for the latter and now column selection is able to span multiple pages!

[image]